# i can not change month names. bootstrapMaterialDatePicker?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

i can not change month name, i tried many ways but it does not work, here my codes.

Html ;

```
 <div class="form-line">
   <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"   name="tarih" placeholder="gg/aa/yyyy" />
      </div>
```

Js;

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        clearButton: false,
        okText:"Tamam",
        cancelText:"İptal",
       monthNames: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'],
monthsShort: ["Oca", "Şub", "Mar", "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem", "Ağu", "Eyl", "Eki", "Kas", "Ara"],
dayNamesMin: [ "Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct" ],
      time: false,

    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: i tried it too, but it didnt work, im using the library, https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation: https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker the prerequisites are **jquery**, **momentjs** (the languages are managed by moments) and **Material Font Icons** (for the icons... :) ).

So we have to include those libraries and set:

```
lang:'tr'
```

for Turkish language.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            clearButton: false,
            lang : 'tr',
            okText:"Tamam",
            cancelText:"İptal",
            time: false
    });
});
```

```css
 /*This is the css file you find in the documentation zip file.*/

.dtp { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); z-index: 2000; font-size: 14px; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
.dtp > .dtp-content { background: #fff; max-width: 300px; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); max-height: 520px; position: relative; left: 50%; }
.dtp > .dtp-content > .dtp-date-view > header.dtp-header { background: #689F38; color: #fff; text-align: center; padding: 0.3em; }

.dtp div.dtp-date, .dtp div.dtp-time { background: #8BC34A; text-align: center; color: #fff; padding: 10px; }
.dtp div.dtp-date > div { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.dtp div.dtp-actual-month { font-size: 1.5em; }
.dtp div.dtp-actual-num { font-size: 3em; line-height: 0.9; }
.dtp div.dtp-actual-maxtime { font-size: 3em; line-height: 0.9; }
.dtp div.dtp-actual-year { font-size: 1.5em; color: #DCEDC8; }
.dtp div.dtp-picker { padding: 1em; text-align: center; }

.dtp div.dtp-picker-month, .dtp div.dtp-actual-time { font-weight: 500; text-align: center; }
.dtp div.dtp-picker-month { padding-bottom:20px!important; text-transform: uppercase!important; }

.dtp .dtp-close { position: absolute; top: 0.5em; right: 1em; }
.dtp .dtp-close > a { color: #fff; }
.dtp .dtp-close > a > i { font-size: 1em; }

.dtp table.dtp-picker-days { margin: 0; min-height: 251px;}
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days, .dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr, .dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > td { border: none; }
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > td {  font-weight: 700; font-size: 0.8em; text-align: center; padding: 0.5em 0.3em; }
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > td > span.dtp-select-day { color: #BDBDBD!important; padding: 0.4em 0.5em 0.5em 0.6em;}
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > td > a, .dtp .dtp-picker-time > a { color: #212121; text-decoration: none; padding: 0.4em 0.5em 0.5em 0.6em; border-radius: 50%!important; }
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > td > a.selected{ background: #8BC34A; color: #fff; }
.dtp table.dtp-picker-days tr > th { color: #757575; text-align: center; font-weight: 700; padding: 0.4em 0.3em; }

.dtp .p10 > a { color: #689F38; text-decoration: none; }
.dtp .p10 { width: 10%; display: inline-block; }
.dtp .p20 { width: 20%; display: inline-block; }
.dtp .p60 { width: 60%; display: inline-block; }
.dtp .p80 { width: 80%; display: inline-block; }

.dtp a.dtp-meridien-am, .dtp a.dtp-meridien-pm { position: relative; top: 10px; color: #212121; font-weight: 500; padding: 0.7em 0.5em; border-radius: 50%!important;text-decoration: none; background: #eee; font-size:1em; }
.dtp .dtp-actual-meridien a.selected { background: #689F38; color: #fff; }

.dtp .dtp-picker-time > .dtp-select-hour { cursor: pointer; }
.dtp .dtp-picker-time > .dtp-select-minute { cursor: pointer; }

.dtp .dtp-buttons { padding: 0 1em 1em 1em; text-align: right; }

.dtp.hidden, .dtp .hidden { display: none; }
.dtp .invisible { visibility: hidden; }

.dtp .left { float: left; }
.dtp .right { float: right; }
.dtp .clearfix { clear: both; }

.dtp .center { text-align: center; }

.dtp-picker-year{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.year-picker-item{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dtp-actual-year:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dtp-actual-year.disabled:hover{
    cursor: inherit;
}
.year-picker-item:hover{
    color:#689F38;
}

.year-picker-item.active{
    color:#689F38;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dtp-select-year-range{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/2.7.1/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.5.10/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-line">
   <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"  name="tarih" placeholder="gg/aa/yyyy" />
</div>
```